# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape' - when resizing image using scikit-image

Tags: scikit-image, image-preprocessing

I'm trying to iterate through a directory and resize every image using scikit-image but I keep getting the following error:

```
b'scene01601.png'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "preprocessingdatacopy.py", line 16, in <module>
    image_resized = resize(filename, (128, 128))
  File "/home/briannagopaul/PycharmProjects/DogoAutoencoder/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skimage/transform/_warps.py", line 104, in resize
    input_shape = image.shape
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

My code:

```
import skimage
from sklearn import preprocessing
from skimage import data, color
import os
from skimage.transform import resize, rescale
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import os
directory_in_str = "/home/briannagopaul/imagemickey/"
directory = os.fsencode(directory_in_str)
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    print(file)
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    if filename.endswith(".png"):
        image_resized = resize(filename, (128, 128))
        img = mpimg.imread(file)
        imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
        plt.show()
        filename.shape()
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to get the shape of the fileNAME rather than the actual FILE. The filename is a string, which doesn't have the `shape()` attribute. You're going to have to load the actual file into a variable, then call `shape()` on that variable

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried using ```x = file.open()``` and then resized x and got the same error. Do you have any suggestions on how I should go about loading the file? @JasonKLai

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, unless the code is run in the same directory as the image, you are going to want to specify the directory in the filename:

```
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    print(file)
    filename = directory_in_str + os.fsdecode(file)
```

But to address your question, you are already reading the image via the `mpimg.imread` line and storing this image as a numpy array called `img`. With that `img` variable, you can run it through the rest of your lines:

```
    if filename.endswith(".png"):
        img = mpimg.imread(filename)
        image_resized = resize(img, (128, 128))
        imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
        plt.show()
        print(img.shape)
```

Note that I changed two separate calls to `filename` to `img` instead. That's because `filename` is simply the name of the file and not the actual file, which in your case was called `img`.